# Python regex for blocks of code?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How do I created a regex that can match a start of a line and also all the following lines starting with tab? For example

```
not keyword ;
    not this line ;
keyword and random text ;
    this line ;
    this line ;
    and this line ;
not keyword ;
```

I want to be able to match starting from '^keyword' to 'and this line ;'

Thank you.

edit. I'm trying to remove Maya's MEL code for the node I don't need. The actual code looks like this, with multiple lines of setAttr with tab indent.

```
createNode mentalrayOptions ......... ;
    setAttr .............. ;
```

I load the entire text into 1 variable with

```
with open( 'path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
```

the regex I tried seem to find the starting point correctly but I can't get the end point correctly. It either matches 1 line, not matching anything at all or matches all the way to the end of file.

```
match = re.search( r'(^createNode mentalrayOptions)(.*\n)(^\t)' ,content, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried?

Comment: Are you trying to parse a CFG with RegEx?

Comment: I was trying to delete blocks of unwanted nodes from Maya file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
^keyword.*(?:\n^\t.*)*
```

Flags:

- `m` for mutiline, so `^` works.
- not `s` so `.` does not match new-lines.

Explanation:

- `^keyword` - Start of the line with `keyword`
- `.*` - match until the end of the line
- `(?:\n^\t.*)*` - each of these matches another line that begins with a tab. Note that we hat to match the new-line, so take care if you have other line separators.

Working example: http://www.regex101.com/r/jP8yH0

Naturally, if you are trying to match *real* blocks of code, this can fail quickly - for example by comments or string literals.

Comment: Thank you. How do I specify multiple flags?

Comment: @Panupat You only need one flag here, `flags=re.MULTILINE`. You do **not** want Singleline/Dotall - that will break the pattern. When you need it, you set multiple flags using bitwise OR: `re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE`.